# How to set a constant decimal value

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm using C# to set a default value for a decimal value in my config class

```
public class ConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
        [ConfigurationProperty("paymentInAdvanceAmount", **DefaultValue = 440m**)]
        public decimal PaymentInAdvanceAmount
        {
            get { return (decimal)base["paymentInAdvanceAmount"]; }
            set { base["paymentInAdvanceAmount"] = value; }
        }
}
```

but it won't be compiled and throws an error

**An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression**

I found a post says: **"It's not a bug.  "1000M" is merely shorthand for "new Decimal(1000)", which involves a method call, which means it's not considered a constant.  Just because the compile lets you pretend it's a constant most of the time, doesn't mean you can all of the time."**

Now, how do I workaround it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942803/why-c-sharp-decimals-cant-be-initialized-without-the-m-suffix

Answer (score 14):

I finally found out it I enter "440" instead of 440m or 440.
It got compiled and runs well

Comment: That is not a constant decimal value. *But* the DefaultValue-Attribute doesn't take a decimal as attribute, it just converts it later. Having an Attribute with an explicit decimal parameter it will throw again...

Answer (score 5):

I found that if you set a default value for a decimal property and specified that value in quotes, it did not work for me with a WinForms control and .NET 3.5.

When ever I right clicked on the property in the designer "Properties" window and selected the "Reset" option I got the message "Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'.

To get it to work I had to use the same code as tphaneuf suggested i.e.

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Decimal), "440")]
public decimal TestValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, in .Net 4.0. I needed to set DefaultValue to decimal.MaxValue. I'm not sure how Codeplex will wrap this, but it had to be written as:

[DefaultValue(typeof(decimal), "79228162514264337593543950335")] 
public decimal StockLimit { get; set; }

Answer (score 4):

You should place 440 inside quotation marks, like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("paymentInAdvanceAmount", DefaultValue = "440")]
```

Comment: This is in fact the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 440 and leave out the 'M'.  I get no compilation errors, and this program works as expected:

```
namespace WindowsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1( )
        {
            InitializeComponent( );
            AttributeCollection attributes = 
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( mTextBox1 )[ "Foo" ].Attributes;           
            DefaultValueAttribute myAttribute =
               ( DefaultValueAttribute ) attributes[ typeof( DefaultValueAttribute ) ];

            // prints "440.1"
            MessageBox.Show( "The default value is: " + myAttribute.Value.ToString( ) );
        }
    }

    class mTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private decimal foo;       
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue( 440.1 )]
        public decimal Foo
        {
            get { return foo; }
            set { foo = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It got compiled but anthoer error occurs when running the App

The default value for the property 'paymentInAdvanceAmount' has different type than the one of the property itself

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code which shows us the problem then?

Comment: This won't help you for default values that are outside the range of Double, though.

Comment: Well, that was not the question, the question specifically said "440".

Comment: Aside from that point, none of the constructors even take a double, so it is a moot point.  Don't see why that would get me a downvote...

Comment: Downvote is correct for that, because you do not enter a decimal. DefaultValue-Attribute doesn't take a decimal parameter in this case but a float maybe? It is converted though at runtime.