# Having an actual decimal value as parameter for an attribute (example xUnit.net's [InlineData]

Tags: c#, decimal, xunit.net

I'm trying to do unit testing with [xUnit.net](https://github.com/xunit/xunit). I want a 'Theory' test with '[InlineData]' which includes 'decimals':

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(37.60M)]
public void MyDecimalTest(decimal number)
{
    Assert.Equal(number, 37.60M);
}
```

This is not possible because you cannot create a [decimal as a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942803/why-c-sharp-decimals-cant-be-initialized-without-the-m-suffix).

Question:
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Also see [Why “decimal” is not a valid attribute parameter type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192833/)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should be able use the String value in the Attribute and set the Parameter type to Decimal, it get's converted automatically by the Test Framework as far as I can tell.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("37.60")]
public void MyDecimalTest(Decimal number)
{
    Assert.Equal(number, 37.60M);
}
```

If this doesn't work then you can manually convert it by passing in a String parameter.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("37.60")]
public void MyDecimalTest(String number)
{
    var d = Convert.ToDecimal(number);
    Assert.Equal(d, 37.60M);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. A little cleaner than casting the other value to double as well. Still hacky though.

Comment: @TimPohlmann I've updated my answer based on further experiments, where the tests pass on my machine

Comment: Yeah this works. I tried it before but had a different issue failing and I just assumed it had converted it to a double. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: Consider `Convert.ToDecimal(number, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)` or equivalently `Convert.ToDecimal(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` if there is a possibility the current culture uses a different number format. Otherwise this may come out as 3760 (three thousand seven hundred and sixty).

Comment: In order to first code snippet, for me it doesn't compile.
`The value is not convertible to the method parameter 'number' of type 'decimal'.`

Comment: @PiotrKwiatek - It should compile, but could fail to run. See Jeppe's comment. As I cannot see how xunit does the conversion I'm guessing it must be a culture related thing. You may need to use your culture's decimal point character instead of `.`.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of `InlineData`, use `MemberData` as shown [here](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/). This gives you much greater flexibility in setting up multiple tests and allows the use of decimals or any other non-constant type.

```
public class CalculatorTests  
{

    public static TheoryData<decimal, decimal, decimal> Data =>
        new()
        {
            { 1.2M, 2.1M, 3.3M },
            { -4.000M, -6.123M, -10.123M }
        };

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Data))]
    public void CanAddTheoryMemberDataProperty(decimal value1, decimal value2, decimal expected)
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();

        var result = calculator.Add(value1, value2);

        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The NUnit solution (Google landed me here) The accepted answers gave me some ideas so after some research came up with with help from [NUnit Sequential Attribute with arrays in Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171321/nunit-sequential-attribute-with-arrays-in-values). The nameof expression is a c# 7 expression

```
[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorTests
{

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data =>
        new List<object[]>
        {
            new object[] { 1.2M, 2.1M, 3.3M },
            new object[] { -4.000M, -6.123M, -10.123M }
        };

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(Data))]
    public void CanAddTheoryMemberDataProperty(decimal value1, decimal value2, decimal expected)
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();

        var result = calculator.Add(value1, value2);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @StillLearning already suggested you can use the `MemberData` attribute. Nowadays there is the TheoryData<> type to make your input typesafe.

I (currently) cannot edit that answer so I'm posting it as another answer.

```
public class CalculatorTests  
{

    public static TheoryData<decimal, decimal, decimal> Data =>
        new()
        {
            { 1.2M, 2.1M, 3.3M },
            { -4.000M, -6.123M, -10.123M }
        };

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Data))]
    public void CanAddTheoryMemberDataProperty(decimal value1, decimal value2, decimal expected)
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();

        var result = calculator.Add(value1, value2);

        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }
}
```