# What is this thing "1.0m" actually? And how can I work around not being able to use it as an attribute argument?

Tags: c#, annotations, decimal, constants, custom-attributes

I am confused, because in C#, a decimal literal such as `1.0m` can be used as a constant field, but not as an argument to an attribute.

```
[Foo(1.0m)] // Error
class C
{
    const decimal constD1 = 1.0m;
}
```

In [a thread at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c0bb351-bc65-46d8-8828-95817b3bd9b3/using-numeric-literal-suffix-m-on-a-constant-value-passed-to-an-attribute?forum=csharplanguage), James Curran replied:

> "1000M" is merely shorthand for "new Decimal(1000)", which involves a
>   method call, which means it's not considered a constant.  Just because
>   the compile lets you pretend it's a constant most of the time, doesn't
>   mean you can all of the time.

But if it is a shorthand for a constructor call, you should be able to do this:

```
class C
{
    const decimal constD2 = new decimal(1.0); // Error
}
```

If I understand [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764001/443836) correctly, it is impossible to pass a decimal to an attribute, which means, I can never successfully do something like this:

```
class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public FooAttribute(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is decimal)
        {
            // Doomed to be dead code?
        }
    }
}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236402/).
By the way, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does not show a compiler error for a decimal constant/literal in an attribute value, which is a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-374366).

Here is a full example:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Foo("")]
    [Foo(new string(new char[] { }))] // Error 1
    [Foo(1.0m)] // Error 1 (no error in ReSharper)
    [Foo(new decimal(1.0))] // Error 1
    class C
    {
        static readonly string s1 = "";
        static readonly string s2 = new string(new char[] {});
        static readonly decimal d1 = 1.0m;
        static readonly decimal d2 = new decimal(1.0);

        const string constS1 = "";
        const string constS2 = new string(new char[] {}); // Error 2
        const decimal constD1 = 1.0m;
        const decimal constD2 = new decimal(1.0); // Error 2

        // Error 1:
        // An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or 
        // array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

        // Error 2:
        // The expression being assigned to (...) must be constant

    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
    class FooAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public FooAttribute(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is decimal)
            {
                // Doomed to be dead code?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is this thing "1.0m" actually? And how can I work around the fact that I cannot use it as an argument to an attribute? The only solution I can think of is to sacrify type safety and do this if dealing with a custom attribute:

```
[Bar("1.0")]
class C
{
}

class BarAttribute : Attribute
{
    public BarAttribute(string decimalAsString)
    {
        decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(decimalAsString);
        ...
    }
}
```

When dealing with NUnit's `TestCaseAttribute`, I would do something similar. According to [NUnit docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5), NUnit converts the type automatically.

```
[TestCase("1.0")]
public void Test(decimal d)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what new information you're looking for. `1.0m` is a decimal literal, which is a constant expression as far as the C# compiler is concerned, but cannot be represented as a constant value for the CLR, hence you can't specify it in an attribute argument. A string representation is about as close as you can get, basically.

Comment: Yes, admittedly, it was hard to put my confusion into a question form at all. An implicit question of mine has been whether I missed something or misunderstood something. I guess you have already answered that, as you have not pointed out mistakes. You also answered my question about what the best workaround is. I still do not get the "C# compiler constant yes, CLR constant no"-thing beyond a "That's how it is, just remeber it"-level. And I still wonder why you cannot "const decimal constD2 = new decimal(1.0)" if "1.0m" is really just a shorthand.

Comment: It's not really just a shorthand for a constructor, at the language level. The best thing to do is compile some code which has `const decimal x = 1.0m;` and then see what the IL looks like...

Comment: @JonSkeet: C# allow `Decimal` values to be specified as default values for parameters.  By my understanding, default parameter values are attributes; would that not imply that it must be possible to encode encode `Decimal` values within CIL (by specifying the type and sequence of bytes required to represent the value in that type)?

Comment: @supercat: Good question. It looks like it encodes it as a separate attribute (`DecimalConstantAttribute`). There are other similar constant attributes available, e.g. for `DateTime`. They even show up under reflection for `ParameterInfo.DefaultValue` - so the framework has some significant knowledge about that. Just not enough to use it for attribute constructors, apparently. Shame :(